# How can I run IPTV video links ending with .ts or .m3u8 on my WordPress site using HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming, m3u8, hls.js, iptv

Hope you are doing well...
I want to open a live video stream on my wordpress site.
I tried many solutions but in the end, I reached this conclusion, I can't open the video so I need to convert the link I want to CDN or proxy in order to make it come over 'HTTPS' because the video from the source which I don't have control over, it's coming over 'HTTP'

--type of .ts file >> video/mp2t, ok failed.

I tried Plugins like (Video.js HLS Player) which supports hls stream and m3u8, and it didn't work giving me the idea I said at first, [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FnKu.png)

so after all of that trying and digging to understand how the football sites open IPTV links on their matches pages, I ended up with nothing work, my goal is to run my premium links I will have later on site, but still not sure if I'll go premium or not, I need to be sure about it first.

The solution about proxy or cdn I mention first, someone tell me that but it's like his idea or imagination in order to overcome this situation? I'm not sure about it too.

and frankly have no idea about cdn or proxy and how can I do that?

Please if I'm wrong tell me about it, I have been for a while searching for solution but I got nothing...

here is the entire idea about desktop using VLC https://youtu.be/0A5FL1EYSNo, but how we can do it on the web!!?

--Final try like this >>using hls.js library >>but not worked on Wordpress with 'HTTPS' ofcourse and I noticed that it's just working for around two minutes or 1 and half then stops and strat throwing the error of 403 (Forbbidn)

```
<h1>mzughbor Live stream</h1>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1"></script>
<video controls id="video"></video>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var videoSrc = 'http://server.....info:8080/live/.../..../19_480.m3u8';
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
  }
</script>
```

```
GET http://.../live/.../file.m3u8?token... 403 (Forbidden)
```

so even if we overcome Http/s soulstion it may not enough?

Please guide me what to do!

THNAKS